# Having trouble getting Entity Framework to savechanges

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have entity framework set up to create an entity object.   No exception is thrown.  When I put in a break point the entity object seems to catch all the data but nothing gets committed to the db.

Take a look:

```
var DBCtx = new FirstHandDM();//DataContext
var newContact = new Contact();//Entity Object

newContact.first_name = firstName.Text;
newContact.last_name = lastName.Text;
newContact.company = companyName.Text;
newContact.phone = phone.Text;
newContact.email = emailAddress.Text;

DBCtx.Contacts.Add(newContact);
DBCtx.SaveChanges();
```

I am running **entity framework 6.0**.

Here is the app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" 
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
                   EntityFramework, 
                   Version=6.0.0.0, 
                   Culture=neutral, 
                   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                   requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
                                    EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, 
                      EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="FirstHandDM" 
           connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\FirstHandDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: SaveChanges() returns an integer indicating the number of objects saved.  What number is returned for you?

Comment: How does your database look like? Maybe you have some constrains/relations, which prevents from proper save?

Comment: I did put in a message box to show what was being returned by the SaveChanges() and, as it should it is returning a 1.   It might be something wrong with my database.  It is using Service-Based Database.

Comment: Could you show us your app.config or web.config?

Comment: LocalDB again... It gets overwritten when you run the application.

Comment: That might be the case, but there doesn't seem to be any commit to the DB during execution.  As in, no data has been inserted, during runtime.   Unless it is not saving it live.